# How to add animation and percentage to knobInput on Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying add the percentage symbol and [animate](https://codepen.io/tailofmoon/pen/BdYOdx) a knob in shiny.

The following is in my app.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        knobInput(
            inputId = "knoby",
            label = "Hello World:",
            value = 69,
            min = 0,
            max = 100,
            lineCap = "round",
            angleOffset = -125,
            angleArc = 250,
            rotation = 'clockwise',
            fgColor = "#428BCA",
            inputColor = "#428BCA",
            readOnly = TRUE
        ),
        tags$script(HTML(" $(\"knoby\").knob({ 'draw' : function () { $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%') } });"))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In a folder www I have the following .js script:

```
       $('.knob').each(function () {

           var $this = $(this);
           var myVal = $this.attr("rel");
           $this.knob();

           $({
               value: 0
           }).animate({
               value: myVal
           }, {
               duration: 3000,
               easing: 'swing',
               step: function () {
                   $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

               }
           })
       });
```

Where could I be going wrong trying to implement the animation and display the number as a percentage?